# Hows Work Rewrite rules in mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i made a lot of changes in my webapp and the urls were like that..

http://miwebapp.com/public/module/action

But now i changed the directory structure and the public folder is now the webroot folder it's means that does not exists more.

now my urls looks at

http://miwebapp.com/module/action

I want to make a Apache Rewrite to catch the URLS that come with the public word..

Y try this..

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^public/(.+)$ /$i [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

:D Thanks a lot :D

Comment: drop the `public/` part of the `rewriterule`?

Comment: What is happening with your current rules?  Also, are these rules in a `.htaccess` file or in your Apache config?

Comment: They are in .htaccess in the webroot folder :)

Comment: Hi @oblig if i drop public in my rule, my rewriter tells to my web app controller that the public is a module :(

Answer (score 0):

Drop the first RewriteRule. All existing file (size not null + link) and all directories url are caught by your RewriteCondition and you set it to do nothing and be the last rule ([L]).
So everything goes through that only rule.

BTW: I'm not sure if $i does exists, but we use to get $1 instead.

Edit 1:

Yap I saw it too!
But I got the solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d      
RewriteRule ^public/(.+)$ /$1 [NC,L]     

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

this should avoid rewriting all file to index.php in loops! (Note that when you do a redirect, the .htaccess is reprocessed with the new values, [L] just stop the rewrite for the current request)

Comment: Hi @M'vy i replaced de $i to $1 and i drop de first rule, and i got Error 500 and in my Server log got this.. `RewriteRule ^public/(.+)$ /$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]`

Comment: mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.

Comment: Hey @M'vy thanks for your help, i believe that the first rewrite rule automatic will drop the public word and send the new url without the public, next the second rewrite rule catch the new clean url and redirect to the index.php, i'm right? because does'nt work, and the public remains in the url and got the public module does'nt exist :(, any clue?

Comment: The first rule shall rewrite any URL like `/public/something` to `/something` now `something` needs to be in the DocumentRoot of your apache for this to work. The second rule is only here catch reference to non existing files/dir to the `index.php`. BTW, I've read again your post, maybe you should remove the RewriteCond for the first Rule since the URL you are asking is not existing anymore that would never match.